# Persist record instance and use it in multiple pages

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, instance

I am creating a force.com site which will fetch a contact record after successful login (The contact is the person logging in). The site has many VF pages which will be using the contact record and its lookup in some way or other. I do not want to pass the contact record using params as it is exposed in the URL.

I was thinking of querying the contact record once (after the user successfully logs in) and then persisting it throughout the session of the site. Any page which needs the contact fields data will just utilize the persisted record instance. I would like to persist it on the server side instead of using a javascript cookie. Any idea on how it can be done?

Comment: You can use custom settings to store the contact value.

Comment: But then I would need to create and delete custom setting every time the user (contact) logs in and logs out of the force.com site.

Comment: You don't need to delete it if user login again the use same record from custom setting.

Answer (score 0):

So just found out that we can set cookies through the page reference. So I am setting the cookie after successful login in my apex class.

```
 Cookie contactCookie = new Cookie('contact', contact.Id, null, -1, false);

        pref = new PageReference('/apex/Home');
        pref.setRedirect(true);
        pref.setCookies(new Cookie[]{contactCookie});
        return pref;
```

Then reading the cookie in other pages:

```
Map<String, Cookie> cookieMap = ApexPages.currentPage().getCookies();
Cookie contactCookie = cookieMap.get('contact');
contactId = contactCookie.getValue();
```

Comment: If you want to keep the information entirely out of site of the client (cookies can be viewed in browsers) then consider using the new in Winter '16 [session  cache](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_apex_platform_cache.htm).